# Pandas Method chaining: reassigning a column using df.assign()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, method-chaining

I have a dataframe with stock returns in one column, strategy values in another & and another  column called trades with boolean values (True, False).

My desire is to subtract a particular value (tc) from a cell with in the strategy column if the corresponding boolean is True otherwise the cell is left untouched.

This is my code:

```
data_1['strategy'][data_1['trades']]-= tc
```

which runs well. However I would have preferred to use the method of chaining so as to make my code compact.

```
data_1.assign(strategy = lambda x: x['strategy'][x['trades']]-= tc)
```

This code throws an error around the `-=` saying the

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) it:

```
data_1['strategy'] = data_1['strategy'].mask(data_1['trades'], data_1['strategy']-tc)
```

Comment: `data_1.assign(strategy = lambda x: x['strategy'].mask(x['trades'], x['strategy']-tc))`  worked. Thanks a million.